# How to remove array elements like white spaces and other characters using perl

Tags: arrays, perl

How to remove array elements like white spaces and some character other the numbers and alphabets?
I tried the below code. It still prints all the white space and some characters other than numbers and alphabets.

```
my $j=0;
while (my $line = <$file>) {
my $string = substr($line, 0, 10);
@array[$j] = $string;
$j++;
}
s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @array;
foreach my $element (@array) {
print "$element\n";
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of input and the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 2** (after more OP's comments below):

*(Quoting slightly rephrased OP's post + comments):*

> Keep only the array elements which have one or more letter or
>   digit. Remove all other leading and trailing characters.

The complete solution, which is both shorter, more robust and more perl-ish, is `grep` and `map` with multiple operations all packed inside.

```perl
@array = grep { $_ ne q{} } 
         map {
                $_ = substr $_, 0, 10;
                s{\A[^A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]+\z}{}g;
                $_
         } <$file>;
```

**Details:**

`<$file>` returns the entire file contents as an array.
`map` operates on each element, aliased to `$_` by default. It returns `$_` after changes - that's why `$_` is explicitly added at the end, as the last thing `map` evaluates.
`\A` is the beginning of the line.
`\z` is the end of the line.
`[^A-Za-z0-9]+` is any non-{letter or digit} character repeated 1 or more times.
`grep { $_ ne q{} }` removes empty strings.

> Why `s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @array;` isn't working?

This removes leading and trailing *whitespace only*. It does **not** remove other non-{digit or letter} characters, such as `'.'` or `'_'`. It also does **not** remove empty strings from the array, such as those resulting from all-whitespace array elements (e.g., `"\t   \t"`) that have been replaced with an empty string: `""`. For example, this regex substitution will change this 2 element array: `(" . a. ", "\t  \t")` 
into this 2 element array: `(". a.", "")` - not what you want.

**SEE ALSO:**

The docs for [Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) have more details.

Comment: By adding @array = map { tr/A-Za-z0-9//cd; $_ } @array; the array indexes having other characters got removed and at the same time the array elements with characters in between letters are getting printed without those characters (ex: input_data is getting printed as inputdata) which is not expected. And the empty array indexes are still getting printed. Can you please tell me why s/^\s+|\s+\z//g for @array; isn't working?

Comment: Your regex removes leading and trailing white space from each string.

Comment: @techie Please update the question with any extra info about what you want to keep (letters, numbers, underscores, ...?) or remove.

Comment: I want to keep the array elements which have one or more than one letter or number. I want to remove array elements that contain only characters. With your solution the array elements with white spaces were getting printed and the characters which are present in-between the alphabets or numbers are getting removed which is not as desired.